# Display product data with custom shortcodes in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

In Woocommerce, I use 3 different shortcode functions that are displaying:

- The product categories list,
- The product SKU
- Values for a specific attribute.

My 3 function looks like this:

```
function display_woo_sku() {

    global $product;
    return $product->get_sku();

}
add_shortcode( 'woo_sku', 'display_woo_sku' );

function display_woo_farve() {

    global $product;
    return $product->get_attribute( 'farve' );

}
add_shortcode( 'woo_farve', 'display_woo_farve' );

function display_woo_style() {

    global $post, $product;
    $categ = $product->get_categories();
    return $categ;    

}
add_shortcode( 'woo_style', 'display_woo_style' );
```

This actually works, **but throws errors when updating products** and make issues with Facebook Pixel add ons.

I can't see What is wrong with my code, but there must be something wrong since it conflicting with plugins and third party pixel tools.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is making some errors for many reasons… Try this instead:

```
function display_woo_sku() {
    if( ! is_admin() && ! is_product() ) return;

    global $post;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    return $product->get_sku();
}
add_shortcode( 'woo_sku', 'display_woo_sku' );

function display_woo_attr_farve() {
    if( ! is_admin() && ! is_product() ) return;

    global $post;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    return $product->get_attribute( 'farve' );
}
add_shortcode( 'woo_farve', 'display_woo_attr_farve' );

function display_woo_cats() {
    if( ! is_admin() && ! is_product() ) return;

    global $post;

    // $categ = $product->get_categories(); // <== <== <== <== IS DEPRECATED

    return wc_get_product_category_list( $post->ID );
}
add_shortcode( 'woo_cats', 'display_woo_cats' );
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

It should solve your issue…

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!